# how to merge query results in one file adding a header and footer from other two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm doing a query that merge three different queries.

My query looks like this...

```
HEADER ( a query  with only one line of information).    
BODY ( a query with many rows).    
FOOTER ( a query  with only one line of information)
```

I have the three queries independently, but I have to merge them in only one result to be send to a txt file.

I do not have any idea how to do this because in theory the first query must be the first line of the result and the last query must be the foot....

Everything must be in continuous text... the problem is adding header and footer to the result..

Comment: How are you exporting the results to a text file?  Management Studio (Cut and Paste) or SSIS or something else?

Comment: I haven't create the procedure to export the txt file... I would like to merge the three queries before thinking about export.. or do you think is better to solve this problem in the final procedure to export to txt?

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have a tough time doing this in a single query unless you return each row as a single value. For example:

```
;WITH header AS
(
  SELECT rn = 1, val = 'col1,col2,col3'
),
query AS
(
  SELECT rn = 2, val = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), col1)
    + ',' + col2 + ',' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), col3, 112)
  FROM dbo.sometable
),
footer AS
(
  SELECT rn = 3, val = 'footer ----'
)
SELECT val FROM header
UNION ALL
SELECT val FROM query
UNION ALL 
SELECT val FROM footer
ORDER BY rn;
```

Comment: +1 but I would have assumed that all queries returned an equal number of columns. If that where the case (OP?), it would make life a bit easier.

Comment: The header is likely column headers, so they would all be strings, so the union wouldn't work well in that case. It is probably better to return the header and footer as strings, and have the app assemble the three queries on its own.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your answer..I have to generate a txt file with a format like this....
'000000000000020120120 **CUSTOMER1DATA** **CUSTOMER2DATA** **CUSTOMER3DATA** 0000000000END'  Everything is returned as one column in each query but the problem is the "header" must be only one row and the body maybe many rows and the footer just one row...

Comment: I have no idea what that means, sorry

Answer (score -1):

This really helped me in adding header and footer in my extracted dataset. In order to keep equal number of columns in header, footer and extracted dataset we add n number of extra columns using following code:
select a, b,'' as ' ' 
'' as ' ' can add any number of required columns to keep the consistency and would not affect the output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This should be a comment, not an answer.